# Trouble pulling from the same table twice in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Sorry if that title is worded weird. I'm working on a query that pulls a list of people who have memberships at a certain place. The query pulls some demographic info from a `Demographics` table, and last/next visit dates from a `Visit` table. Even when a person is not a member anymore, they remain in the system but their account is flagged with a "transferred" marker (in varchar format). I need to be able to pull a list of *all* members in the system but have a column that shows whether a given member has the transferred flag. The flag field can also be found in the `Demographics` table, and there are many different flags a member can have. A single member might have 10 different flags.

In my head, the immediate solution was to query the `Demographics` table twice, using the first instance to show each member's actual demographic data and the second instance to show the transferred flag. The query runs without errors; however, it still ends up showing *only* transferred members, and I realized the logic I was using didn't quite make sense. I think I'm on the right track but need to fix this issue.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.MemberID,
    d.MemberName,
    d.DateOfBirth,
    [a few other demographic fields blah blah],
    v.LastVisitDate,
    v.NextVisitDate,
    d2.MemberFlag as [Transferred?]

FROM Demographic d JOIN Visit v ON d.MemberID = v.MemberID
    JOIN Demographic d2 ON d.MemberID = d2.MemberID

WHERE d2.MemberFlag LIKE '%transf%'
```

I've tried different types of `JOINs` and nothing has worked, but like I said, I've realized my logic is kind of off. I get the sense the solution will probably turn out to be super simple but my brain just isn't working. Here's what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
MemberID   MemberName    ...    NextVisitDate    Transferred?
------------------------------------------------------------------
1001       John Smith    ...    03/10/2021
1002       Jane Doe      ...    NULL             Transferred
1003       Bob Brown     ...    04/22/2021
1004       Mike Jones    ...    03/17/2021
1005       Ann Green     ...    03/30/2021
1006       Dan White     ...    NULL             Transferred
```

**★★UPDATE★★**

The solution kind of came to me...I decided to try just using a `CASE` with the flag field in the original `Demographics` table rather than try to query the table a second time.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    d.MemberID,
    d.MemberName,
    d.DateOfBirth,
    [a few other demographic fields blah blah],
    v.LastVisitDate,
    v.NextVisitDate,
    (CASE
         WHEN d.MemberFlag LIKE '%transf%' THEN 'Transferred'
         ELSE ''
    END) AS [Transferred?]

FROM Demographic d JOIN Visit v ON d.MemberID = v.MemberID
```

This *almost* works perfectly. I'm still running into a little bit of an issue where any members who do have the transferred flag also end up with a row with a blank flag field, so it's like those people are duplicating. The results now end up looking like the following. Any ideas for how to avoid this?

```
MemberID   MemberName    ...    NextVisitDate    Transferred?
------------------------------------------------------------------
1001       John Smith    ...    03/10/2021
1002       Jane Doe      ...    NULL             
1002       Jane Doe      ...    NULL             Transferred
1003       Bob Brown     ...    04/22/2021
1004       Mike Jones    ...    03/17/2021
1005       Ann Green     ...    03/30/2021
1006       Dan White     ...    NULL             
1006       Dan White     ...    NULL             Transferred
```

Comment: Tip: `SELECT DISTINCT` is often a code-smell because it means you're de-duping data that shouldn't be duplicated in the first place. So, **why** are you using `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @Dai it has honestly just become a habit because the database I have to work with has terrible structure and half the time if I **don't** use `SELECT DISTINCT`, I get a bunch of duplicate results. But does that even have anything to do with the problem I'm asking about?

Comment: Well, you said you're having issues _and_ I saw you're using select-distinct - I assumed it was related.

Comment: Well I just got rid of the `DISTINCT` part and tested it again—this simple query is now taking *multiple minutes* to run and as of this second, has yet to finish. Ignoring this issue for the moment, do you have any other ideas? Is my original logic even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, it looks like duplicated data that you have the member id, name and birth date in the demographics table that make multiple rows per.  Not cool, but if that's what you have.

If the 'MemberID' is the unique ID and the member's name and birth date will be the same on every row, then you could apply a group by the memberID and just do a MAX() on all fields you want that wont change.  Ex: If my birth day is March 5, 2000, and I have 10 records with birth day for me are all March 5, 2020, then MAX(d.DateOfBirth) would still yield March 5.  So with that premise in mind, this query might help get what you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
        d.MemberID,
        max( d.MemberName ) MemberName,
        max( d.DateOfBirth ) DateOfBirth,
        max( each other blah blah fields) blahField1,
        coalesce( max( v.LastVisitDate ), '' ) LastVisitDate,
        coalesce( max( v.NextVisitDate ), '' ) NextVisitDate,
        max( CASE WHEN d.MemberFlag LIKE '%transf%' THEN 'Transferred'
                 ELSE ''
            END) AS Transferred
    from
        Demographic d 
            JOIN Visit v 
                ON d.MemberID = v.MemberID
    group by
        d.MemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE to pull the transferred flag and then left-join to it.

```
    with transferred as
        (
        select distinct MemberID, 'Y' as transfer_flag
        from demographic
        where MemberFlag like '%transf%'
        )
    select distinct
       d.MemberID, 
       d.MemberName,
       d.DateOfBirth, 
       v.LastVisitDate, 
       v.NextVisitDate, 
       t.transfer_flag
    from demographic d
    join visit v
      on v.MemberID = v.MemberID
    left join transferred t
      on t.MemberID = d.MemberID
```

In sql-server, it may look a bit different. I haven't used that dbms, but it may look something like this...

```
    with transferred (MemberID, transfer_flag)
    as
        (
        select distinct MemberID, 'Y' 
        from demographic
        where MemberFlag like '%transf%'
        )
    select distinct
       d.MemberID, 
       d.MemberName,
       d.DateOfBirth, 
       v.LastVisitDate, 
       v.NextVisitDate, 
       t.transfer_flag
    from demographic d
    join visit v
      on v.MemberID = v.MemberID
    left join transferred t
      on t.MemberID = d.MemberID
```